# Adding array to a JSON object in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a script that is doing some manipulation on JSON, and then writing them to a file `test.json`.

```
$json = @{
    "A"="Hello world";
    "B"= New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
}

$json2 = @{
    'C'="Foo Bar";
    'D'=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
}


$json.B += $json2

$json | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "test.json"
```

I expected the following `json` to be created:

```
{
    "A":  "Hello world",
    "B":  [
              {
                  "D":  [],
                  "C":  "Foo Bar"
              }
          ]
}
```

however, I found this:

```
{
    "A":  "Hello world",
    "B":  [
              {
                  "D":  "",
                  "C":  "Foo Bar"
              }
          ]
}
```

Any clues as to why `D` doesn't map to an array? Any fixes?

Comment: Change `ConvertTo-Json` to `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you, a silly mistake on my part!

Comment: We all live and learn :)